# DB App with PHP & SQLite Returning Null in Database

Tags: php, database, sqlite, symfony

I'm currently building an ultra basic first name and last name database app to practice my skills with both PHP and SQLite and I have come into a bit of an issue that I can't figure out and I'm ready to pull my hair out over.

I'll try and explain this as best I can, bit of a newbie.

I'm using the Symfony HTTP-Foundation and polyfill-mbstring frameworks, the app is running error free and as expected apart from the issue of the input fields where I add the first name and last name don't seem to be writing to the database. When I view the data in the database, each row appears as NULL.

Here is the function that I have created to add a new client to the database:

```
function addNewClient($firstName, $lastName) {
   global $db;

   try {
      $query = 'INSERT INTO client_summary (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name)';

      $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

      $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $firstName);
      $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $lastName);

      return $stmt->execute();
   } catch(\Exception $e) {
      throw $e;
   }
}
```

Here's the code I am using for the input field

```
<form method="post" action="procedures/add-client.php" class="mt-5">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="<?php if(isset($firstName)) echo $firstName; ?>" placeholder="First Name" required />
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="<?php if(isset($lastName)) echo $lastName; ?>" placeholder="Last Name" />
   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">
      Insert Into Database
   </button>
</form>
```

Then the procedure for adding a new client

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../inc/bootstrap.php';

$firstName = request()->get('first_name');
$lastName = request()->get('last_name');

try {
   $newClient = addNewClient($firstName, $lastName);

   redirect('/index.php');
   $response->send();
   exit;
} catch(\Exception $e) {
   throw $e;
}
```

The bootstrap.php is for the functions.php and connection.php files.

Here is the results in the DB Browser I am using.

[image: Screenshot of DB Browser and the results I am getting]

Surely this is something I'm missing and just need a pair of experienced eyes.

Thanking you in advance,

Stu :)

Comment: Earlier I was getting errors with the code, whereas now I am getting no data being inserted in to the DB

Comment: Fair enough +1...had to ask, because many people abuse the site :-(

Comment: When I was typing out the question, I was worrying I might be over doing it asking another question from the same code as I did yesterday. I was going to delete the post from yesterday but never got around to doing it.

Comment: What is the request() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code, where you are getting the `first_name` and `last_name`, you have an error. Those two names you are pulling from `request()` should match the fields `name` from your input tags on your HTML. So they should be changed for `request()->get('firstName')` and `request()->get('lastName')`.

Comment: You're a legend @diegowc! Thank you so much for this. It's working perfectly :D